# Using jQuery How to check the td element content is in increasing order

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, how to check the td element content is in increasing order?

Thanks

Table is below.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>1010</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1009</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1008</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1007</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only positive values are expected:

```
var prev = -1;
var increasing = true;
$("td").each(function() {
  var n = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  if (n < prev) {
    increasing = false;
  }
  prev = n;
});
```

Comment: With ur code i am able to extract the data but now i have one more requirement .Now i need to extract data one by one and that is only first column of the table.                                                               <table> <tr> <td>1010</td><td>1010 asda</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1009</td><td>1010 asfgjh</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1008</td><td>sdf1010 sdf</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1007</td><td>1010 sdfsdf</td> </tr> </table>

Comment: You can use a positional selector for this: $("tr td:eq(0)"). This select all cells in the first column. Chain it with each() to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply the tablesorter plugin if you want to sort it : http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Otherwise you'd have to iterate through it and do what you want with it

if your table had an id of `mytable`

```
$('#mytable td').each(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).html());
    //do something with val
})
```